# Why "Snir" in Yechezkel 27:5?

Tags: names, geography, ezekiel--the-book, deuteronomy

In [Devarim 3:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.3.9?with=all&lang=bi&aliyot=0) it says that the Tzidonim would call Mt. Chermon "Sirion" and the Amorim would call it "Snir". However, when Yechezkel laments the fall of Tzor, which is in Tzidon, he refers to Chermon as "Snir" ([27:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.27.5?with=all&lang=bi)). Wouldn't it make more sense for him to use the Tzidoni word for it?

Comment: clearly, the answer is טוּר תַּלְגָּא ;)

Comment: @rosends So Yechezkel should have said: "Snow place like home"?